# Getting following error on running build.xml at taskdef level

Tags: java, ant

On running build.xml, getting following error.
build.xml:147: taskdef class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask cannot be found

Tried giving the executable permission to lib folder and all jar files but still no luck

```
<taskdef name="xjc" classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<taskdef name="wsimport" classname="com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport">
    <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
    </classpath>
</taskdef>
```

on mouse hover on taskdef in build.xml, shows following warning 
taskdef class com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader

Comment: Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48770937/how-do-you-modify-an-xjc-block-in-ant-build-xml-for-java-9. Most probably in Java 9+, you'll have to add jaxb classes to classpath.

Comment: Do you actually have jaxb-xjc.jar stored in `${lib.dir}`?